# Strategy to implement an "optional" location permission

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I'm developing an app that would benefit from coarse location data, but the nature of this app is such that many users would have privacy concerns if location permission would be mandatory

**I'm hoping to find a way to provide both options (with and without location perms).**

AFAIK there is no way to enable location perms programmatically in Android.

**All I can think of is to publish two separate app versions in Google Play** but I'm not very excited about "splitting" the download and rating stats between them and the potential development overhead.

**Do you have any ideas to handle this another way or how to make the separate app option as painless as possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference:
It is now possible with the new [Android M runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

The permissions still have to be defined in manifest, so, to avoid enforcing the permission for users with older android versions, use the new `<uses-permission-sdk23 />` element